# Past Perfect vs Past Perfect Continuous

Tags: grammar

In the First Class Complete Edition (official Cambridge book) there's an example:

> None of us (ever ski) before so we had been looking forward  forward to it for months.

Naturally I wrote "None of us  **had ever skied** before so we
had been looking forward to it for months."
But the only right answer, so the book says, is "had ever been skiing".. Why??

To put things into perspective, is is even idiomatic or at least colloquial to say:

> "I have **never** *been playing* football"?

Comment: To me, ***I've never been skiing before*** is syntactically on a par with *I've never **been on holiday** before*, rather than a "continuous" version of *I've never **skied** before*.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is grammatically correct. You can say "had ever skied". But in most cases, when referring to a trip, event or outing, people use the idiomatic phrase "to go skiing" instead of "to ski".

You can find some discussions online where people differentiate between the two phrases and give them more general and specific meanings but it's not clear that there is any objective basis for this.

Comment: But there's no word "go" anywhere in the sentence..

Comment: It could be that they implied it was more about the trip/vacation than the physical activity given that the sentence ends with "...we had been looking forward to it for months." It's not perfect and might be poorly communicated.

Comment: @Ceejay "Go" has two past participles: "gone" and "been", so "*...had ever been skiing...*" is the past perfect of "go".

Comment: @gotube since when has "been" become the form of "go"?

Comment: I don't know the history of the word, but that's the way it is. In this context, "had ever been skiing" is a form of "go skiing", not "be skiing".

Answer (score 0):

This mirrors the 'go fishing / shopping / shooting / hunting // come dancing / shopping ...' 'phase structure', but with 'be' instead of 'go' is far less productive. "Have you never been fishing / dancing / shopping / ... in Wigan?" are idiomatic; notice that they point to a one-off 'achievement'.

Both your answers are correct (as arguably is 'had ever gone skiing'); I'm not sure why a phase structure is *demanded* by the textbook. It's a refined choice.

'Go playing' is far less idiomatic, though "They've gone playing football" sounds an awful lot better than standalone "I've never been playing football". Obviously, the non-phase "I've never been playing football on the airfield when a plane came in to land" is a different situation.